# Implement click listener to ListFragment

Tags: android, click

I'm new and I'm using a FragmentList and i want to caputre de click event. How i can do?
becouse my onitemclick doesn't capture de click :(
I have tried to put focusable textview to false because i read it in one post and nothing to.

```
public class FgShopsInfoList extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
 String[] countries = new String[] {
    "India",
    "Pakistan",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "China",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Nepal",
    "Afghanistan",
    "North Korea",
    "South Korea",
    "Japan"
};

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable/
int[] flags = new int[]{
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher
};

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] currency = new String[]{
    "Indian Rupee",
    "Pakistani Rupee",
    "Sri Lankan Rupee",
    "Renminbi",
    "Bangladeshi Taka",
    "Nepalese Rupee",
    "Afghani",
    "North Korean Won",
    "South Korean Won",
    "Japanese Yen"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shops_info_list, container,false);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = {  R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_shops_info_list, from, to);


    setListAdapter(adapter);



    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Log.e("Xx","A");

}
}
```

And the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="XXXXX"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

     />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
    />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"

         />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: according to your code i don't think your list is even showing...your have to return your view rather than super.onCreateView......
change line return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
to return view

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
//do something here
}
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) is the documentation.

This method will be called when an item in the list is selected. Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

**Parameters**

**l**    The ListView where the click happened

**v**    The view that was clicked within the ListView

**position**    The position of the view in the list

**id**  The row id of the item that was clicked